# Google Sheets Form Submit Trigger Issues

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Basically I am receiving errors about the formsubmit and everything has been changed around multiple times and re-edited PLUS re written but the script just wont budge.

I have deleted and recreated+edited the code multiple times and deleted and recreated the trigger multiple times and to no avail.
I originally made it so only hard edits could work to bring data down to the bottom cells but that is not what I wanted in the end.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function formsubmit()
{
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var email_address = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow()
var lastColumn=sheet.getLastColumn()
var entries=sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastColumn)
for(var i=1; i<=lastColumn; i++)
 {
   var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,i).getValues()
   if(cell==0)
   {
     var previousCell=sheet.getRange((lastRow-1),i).getValues()
     sheet.getRange(lastRow,i).setValues(previousCell)
   }
  }
 }
```

6/23/19 4:48 PM
myFunction
Script function not found: myFunction
formSubmit
6/23/19 4:48 PM.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I believe it is case sensitive.

So Google Sheet is looking for 'form**S**ubmit', when your function is called 'form**s**ubmit' (lower case S)